# Java 8 lambda expression for Tuple2

Tags: lambda, java-8

```
     JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> fin =   res.map(new Function<Tuple2<Integer,Double>, Tuple2<Integer,Double>>() {
           @Override
           public Tuple2<Integer,Double> call(Tuple2<Integer,Double> tuple) {


            Tuple2<Integer, Double> temp =  new Tuple2<>(tuple._1 , (tuple._2/cnt.get(tuple._1)));
            return temp;
           }
         });
```

How to represent this using lambda in Java?

Comment: `res.map(tuple -> new Tuple2<>(tuple._1, tuple._2 / cnt.get(tuple._1)))` Of course this will work only if `Function` is a functional interface, i.e. if it has only a single abstract method `call`.

Comment: Thank you. It works